# how to round the answer in two decimal point

Tags: java

I have simple math example Add, Substract, Divide and Multiply and using variable as double and want answer should be in two decimal point if I use decimals to add substract divide or multiply.

```
    private void jButton_addActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent  
    evt)    {                                            

    double First = Double.parseDouble(jTextField1.getText());
    // Read the Second number
    double Second = Double.parseDouble(jTextField2.getText());
    // Set the Result
    double Result = First + Second;

    jLabel4.setText(String.valueOf(Result));
     }                                           

    private void jButton_substractActionPerformed
   (java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)   
   {                                                  

    double First = Double.parseDouble(jTextField1.getText());
   // Read the Second number
   double Second = Double.parseDouble(jTextField2.getText());
   // Set the Result
   double Result = First - Second;


   jLabel4.setText(String.valueOf(Result));
   }                                                 

    private void jButton_MultiplyActionPerformed  
   (java.awt.event.ActionEvent  evt)   
   {                                                 

    double First = Double.parseDouble(jTextField1.getText());
    // Read the Second number
    double Second = Double.parseDouble(jTextField2.getText());
    // Set the Result
    double Result = First * Second;


    jLabel4.setText(String.valueOf(Result));

  }                                                

   private void jButton_divideActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent 
    evt)   {                                               

    double First = Double.parseDouble(jTextField1.getText());
    // Read the Second number
    double Second = Double.parseDouble(jTextField2.getText());
    // Set the Result
    double Result = First / Second;


    jLabel4.setText(String.valueOf(Result));
    }
```

How to get result rounded to two decimal Points like 12.38 instead of 12.379999

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to round a number to n decimal places in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java)

Comment: There are several other questions in Stack Overflow which should provide you with a solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do this by

```
double round = Math.round(number * 100.0) / 100.0;
```

where `number` is your decimal number

To break it down -

```
double number = 3.14159;
number = Math.round(number * 100);
number = number/100;
```

The output will be 3.14

Answer (score 0):

use setRoundingMode to tell it how many decimal points you want.